# Convert DateTime in DataRow to a formatted date string

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, datarow

I'm hoping that there is something I am not seeing clearly, but to simplify, I have the below code

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  row["StartOn"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row["StartOn"].ToString()).ToString("MMM dd").ToString();
}
```

If I run the below code I get “Aug 09”

```
Convert.ToDateTime(row["StartOn"].ToString()).ToString("MMM dd").ToString();
```

If I look to see what is in row[“StartOn”] after this change it contains “8/9/2016 12:00:00 AM”

I'm unable to format my DataRow to an "MMM dd" format

Comment: After formatting what do you expect to see? MMM is abbreviation of the month. dd is the date. So what you get is correct.

Comment: Since im iterating through each row, I would like to convert the rows value of "8/9/2016 12:00:00 AM" to a string value of "Aug 09".. It seems when I try to replace the row["StartOn"] value it fails. because it does not save the new formated string. The DataRow will still say "8/9/2016 12:00:00 AM" after my iteration is complete

Comment: You are trying to store a string of "Aug 9" into a datetime.  ConvertToDatetime will put that back into a DateTime object, assuming, since you don't provide it, the year is 2016, and the time is 12:00 AM, the start of the day

Comment: Change column type to string.

Comment: No, don't change column type to string.  Rather, whenever you are going to output the column, THEN format it to only output the month and date.  There is no reason why you can't have a fully qualified DateTime in the database, but only use the month and date when you want to output it or use it in any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StartOn is apparently a DateTime type.  DateTime types do NOT have a format.  They are an object that specifies year, month, date, and time (among other things).  All you are doing in your conversions is stripping out the time so that the new datetime has a time of 12:00 am.

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what I want to do, the time is irrelevant to me, and i need to replace the DataRows value with "Aug 09"

Comment: You are not understanding.  You can not just store a string in a DateTime type object.  It is apparent that the table's row's "StartOn" field is a DateTime object.  So in order to put that string into "StartOn", you are doing a Convert.ToDateTime, which adds all the information a DateTime object needs (year, month, date, time, etc)

Comment: Gotcha, I was under the impression that row["StartOn"] was still a DataRow type and its value could be replaced with a string. Is the best solution to create a new DataTable and do add string values to the new table?

Comment: No, you probably do not need to replace "StartOn" with anything.  Leave it as a fully qualified DateTime.  Then whenever you use it, for output or whatever else you want, then you can use only the parts you are interested in.

Comment: It may be that what you are missing is the fact that in C#, when you take a row from a datatable and index it with a string, you are referencing a specific column (or field) within that table row.  The column (or field) which has the name given by your string.

Comment: I see, so this could be a referencing issue, and your above comment states the best way to go about fixing this is to output my DateTime how ever i please on the front end. This did work for me, and you were a great help, Thank You.. This was the correct format for my gridview <asp:BoundField DataField="StartOn" DataFormatString="{0:MMM dd}" HeaderText="Date" />

Answer (score 0):

What is `dt.Columns["StartOn"]`. I suspect this is `DateTime`. Let me break down your single line of code into 2 lines.

```
string s = Convert.ToDateTime(row["StartOn"].ToString()).ToString("MMM dd").ToString();
row["StartOn"] = s;
```

In line 1, you are converting a `DateTime` object to a string object. But on line 2, you are implicitly converting your `string` to a `DateTime`

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("StartOn", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Today);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    var data = Convert.ToDateTime(row["StartOn"].ToString()).ToString("MMM dd").ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"Type of stored data is: {data.GetType()}");
    row["StartOn"] = data;
}

// fetch the data
var fetchedData = dt.Rows[0][0];
Console.WriteLine($"Type of Fetched Data is: {fetchedData.GetType()}");
```

BTW, you can use the below line to do the conversion

```
((DateTime)row["StartOn"]).ToString("MMM dd");
```