# if statement inside asp dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, codeblocks

I have the code below in ASP

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataTextFormatString="{0:MMM dd}" OnSelectedIndexChanged="eDates_SelectedIndexChanged" s ID="eDates" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

I want to know if i can write an if condition that checks to see if the value of the dropdownlist item can be converted to datetime and if not DataTextFormatString = "". Can i write a code block in this to determine if the dropdownlist item can be converted to datetime and if not change the DataTextFormatString attribute to null or ""

Comment: ever thought about code behind?

Comment: my DataSource for the DDL is a datatable. I've actually asked this before recently and I was told I cannot convert a DataTime to string in my datatable per the link below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046827/convert-datetime-in-datarow-to-a-formatted-date-string

Comment: I recommend you don't bind to data tables anyways. Bind to model objects. It's much easier to swap them out and do processing on them.

Comment: You can do this by implementing `eDates_DataBound` event.  `DataBound` event allows you to inspect each element and modify accordingly; You can write your own logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataTextFormatString is a string that is applied to each entry in the drop down list to format its text on the output. This string does not change for every entry, rather the same string is applied to all entries. Entering a conditional statement in server tags on this page would just make that statement get evaluated when the page is rendered at the server level. I do not believe there is a way to accomplish what you are trying to do without first formatting the data and passing it to the Drop Down List's data source from code behind.

Comment: I believe you are correct, while its true you can put conditional C# code blocks in an area such is this, It would not work appropriately for a data bound item. Thanks